# Is my Ubuntu mirror down?

Tags: apt, updates, archive

It seems like http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com is down.
I'm trying `sudo apt update` but it says
`Cannot initiate the connection to ua.archive.ubuntu.com:80`
Is there any website with servers status, and info when it will be repaired?

Also it says

```
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How I can fix this issue? Should I just use another mirror or a mirror server from another country?

Fix issue:  http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2018/03/how-to-change-ubuntu-repository-mirror-sources.html

Comment: According to https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ua.archive.ubuntu.com *It's not just you! ua.archive.ubuntu.com is down.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on [Ubuntu mirrors status](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors), at this exact moment only one mirror from Ukraine  is up to date (`mirror.volia.net`) and others are some hours or days behind.

[image]

So when you use `http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com` it will automatically picks the most up to date one which currently is not working correctly.

You have to inform the people behind `mirror.volia.net` (Volia Broadband) that their mirror is not working correctly or wait for them to find about and fix the issue.

You can also change your mirrors to some other mirrors from Ukraine which are almost up to date (Two hours behind at this moment):

```
http://ubuntu.mirrors.omnilance.com/ubuntu/
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I informed Volia Broadband about this problem.