# Windows Subsystem for Linux 2: Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Tags: apt, 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 with Windows Subsystem for Linux following [this instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual).

When I run `sudo apt install update`, I get this errors:

```
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Long time ago (before formatting my PC), I didn't have any problem.

I was unable to find any working solution on Internet. I don't have any VPN (some people say that that is the problem).

**Edit 1**

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error) and I followed the @fossfreedom♦ answer. If I try the temporary solution, all works until I reboot. I used:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null
```

However, if I try the permanent solution, I get an error:

```
$ echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base > /dev/null
tee: /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base: No such file or directory
```

I still haven't tried the "package-management issues" in that answer, since I don't think that is the problem

**Edit 2**

All Ubuntu mirrors I checked (Spanish) are "Up to date", following @NotTheDr01ds comment. So that is not the problem.

**Edit 3: Solution**

Since the question was flagged as duplicated and closed, I can't answer my own question with the solution I figured out, so I add the solution here.

This is the original content of the file `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.28.176.1
```

Since this file is generated every time you start WSL, the changes from:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null
```

are removed (command from this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error)). Therefore, you have to follow the instructions shown in the file, I used the command used on this other [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347712/make-etc-resolv-conf-changes-permanent-in-wsl-2):

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "[network]" > /etc/wsl.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "generateResolvConf = false" >> /etc/wsl.conf'
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

And now changes are permanent.

I don't know what I'm doing or why I had this problem (I'm a basic user), but if somebody wants to explain it for the future, he/she is welcomed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is my Ubuntu mirror down?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162937/is-my-ubuntu-mirror-down).  There was a temporary outage earlier today that would have corresponded roughly to the timeframe of your post.  If you are still having the problem, though, let me know.  Otherwise, click the "This solved my problem" in the header.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds that doesn't solve my issue. Today all servers are "Up to date". I'm focusing on Spanish servers. I updated my question with useful information.

Comment: Thanks for your answers provided as updates. Very useful